# Netbeans created JAR classpath

Tags: netbeans, jar, classpath

I have setup inside Netbeans to include a classpath pointing to a directory (properties) on my project folder as seen in the picture below. The folder contains the properties files that the project is using.

[image: Setting up classpath in Netbeans]

Now the problem is that when I use the Netbeans Clean and Build function, it generates the dist folder alright. No properties folder is created... I manually copy over the properties folder in the project folder to this dist folder.

However, the program is not able to detect the properties files. Anyone have any clue as to why it can work inside Netbeans (F6 function key) and not able to work when in command line.

(I simply typed at command line: java -jar MyApp.jar)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using this method explained here: http://creechy.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/adding-custom-class-path-entries-to-a-netbeans-java-application-project/